# iOS presented UINavigationController gets dismissed after it performs a popViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my app i present a `UINavigationController` modally with a `UIViewController` as its `rootViewController`. I do it in form style. I added a second `UIViewController` which is also in form style and i can push to it fine. However when i perform a `popViewController` action after the second `UIViewcontroller` gets popped onto the first, the whole modally presented `UIViewController` gets dismissed. However i don't perform any dismissing and the dismissing function doesn't get triggered by accident either.

Any ideas why it's happening?

Sincerely,

Zoli

EDIT:

That's how i'm presenting the modal viewcontrollers with a navcontroller:

```
if(!welcomeScreenAlreadyPresented) {

    welcomeScreenViewController = [[WAWelcomeViewController alloc]init];
}

welcomeScreenNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:welcomeScreenViewController];
[welcomeScreenNavController setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[welcomeScreenNavController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[welcomeScreenNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:welcomeScreenNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That's how i'm navigation in WAWelcomeViewController.m

```
registerViewController = [[WARegisterViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:registerViewController animated:YES];
```

And in WARegisterViewController.m that's how i pop back

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you are using to do this?

Comment: ARC enabled?...registerViewController with _weak property?

Comment: ARC enabled and that was my first thought too. The problem was somewhere else tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is put the viewController you want to push inside another `UINavigationController`.

```
registerViewController = [[WARegisterViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *modalNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:registerViewController]; // autorelease if you are not using ARC

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

You might want to add the `modalNavigationController` as a property to later call `popViewControllerAnimated:` on it.

Comment: on the contrary. It's a navigationcontroller presented modally. i want to navigate with the modal viewcontroller's navigationcontroller, i don't want to dismiss the modal viewcontroller at all

Comment: That's the proper way to do it, yes. I was doing it the same way. Adding it as property is not really necessary because UIViewControllers have a navigationController property anyway, so self.navigationController will always point to the navController that manages the current UIViewController.
However the problem was somewhere else, and i'm too ashamed to tell you what it was :) Anyway, thanks for the help, +1 and accepted solution!